If a sequence $a_n$ satisfies the following two properties, does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n^k} - L)$ converge?
Let $a_n$ be a positive, increasing sequence satisfying the following two properties:
$S_k :=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n^k}$ converges for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
And $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty} S_k = L \in \mathbb{R}$
Is it the case that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (S_k - L)$ converges for all sequences satisfying the properties above?
This seems to be the case for all the sequences $a_n$ that I have tried (using a computer) but I am unable to prove that it converges, or find a counter-example.

I think* the properties:

$a_n$ is a positive, increasing sequence

$S_k :=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n^k}$ converges for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$,

$\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty} S_k = L \in \mathbb{R},$


are equivalent to the properties:

$a_n$ is a positive, increasing sequence

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges,

$a_1\geq 1.$


Looking at the second trio of properties, define $m$ to be the amount of members of $a_n$ that are equal to $1,\ $ that is, either $m=0,$ or $a_1=a_2=\ldots=a_m=1$ and $a_{m+1} > 1.$
In particular, $L= m.$
Next, since $\frac{1}{a_n} \leq \frac{1}{a_{m+1}}$ for all $n\geq m+1,$  we see that $\frac{1}{a_n^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{a_n}\cdot \frac{1}{a_n^k} \leq \frac{1}{a_{m+1}a_n^k}$ for all $n\geq m+1,$ and so
$$S_{k+1}-L = S_{k+1}-m $$
$$ =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n^{k+1}} - m $$
$$ =\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n^{k+1}} $$
$$ \leq \frac{1}{a_{m+1}} \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n^k} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{a_{m+1}} (S_k-m) = \frac{1}{a_{m+1}} (S_k-L). $$
Since $S_{k+1}-L \leq \frac{1}{a_{m+1}} (S_k-L)$ and $\frac{1}{a_{m+1}} < 1,$ it follows that the sequence $(S_k-L)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is at most a decreasing geometric sequence with common ratio $<1,$ and therefore it's series converges.
If you want a formal proof for $*$ at the start of my answer then I will try to provide it. But basically it's because if $a_1<1,$ then we will have $L=\infty \not\in\mathbb{R}.$ So then property $3$ in the (second trio of properties) must be true.
